# Can't correctly pass data through Intent from ListView

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, android-intent

I try to pass data item that I choose in `ListView` to the next `Activity`. But all that I can, is that second activity is empty or `nullpoinexception` error. I did it with `RecycleView`, but with `ListView` there some problems.

Main activity:

```
public class ListViewPlaces extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseFirestore mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference placeRef = mFirestore.collection("Places");
Query query;
ListView mListView;
String name;
Places places;
ArrayList<Places> randomPlaceList;
PlaceAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_places);
    mListView = findViewById(R.id.place_list);

    randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();

    Boolean l_check1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("1");
    Boolean l_check2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("2");

    if (l_check2){
        query = placeRef.whereEqualTo("colour", "red");
    } else if (l_check1){
        query = placeRef.whereEqualTo("size", "1");
    } else {
        query = placeRef.whereEqualTo("size", "2");
    }
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Places> placesList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Places place = document.toObject(Places.class);
                        placesList.add(place);
                    }
                    int placeCount = placesList.size();
                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                    ArrayList<Places> randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                        randomPlaceList.add(placesList.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount)));
                    }
                    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.place_list);
                    mAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(randomPlaceList, getBaseContext());
                    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
            }
        });


        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Places places = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Card_activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", places.getName());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

My model class:

```
public class Places {
private String image, name;

public Places() {

}

public Places(String image, String name) {
    this.image = image;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() { return image; }
public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

Custom Adapter:

```
class PlaceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places> {

private ArrayList<Places> dataSet;
Context mContext;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name_text;
    ImageView image_text;
}

public PlaceAdapter(ArrayList<Places> dataSet, Context context ) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_list, dataSet);

    this.dataSet = dataSet;
    this.mContext = context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Places places = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    final View result;

    if (converView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        converView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
        viewHolder.name_text = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.text_image_id);
        viewHolder.image_text = (ImageView) converView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);

        result = converView;

        converView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) converView.getTag();
        result = converView;
    }

    viewHolder.name_text.setText(places.getName());
    Glide.with(getContext()).load(places.getImage()).into(viewHolder.image_text);

    return converView;
```

And the second activity, where I pass data:

```
public class Card_activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView mTextView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.massive_places);

        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.head_name);
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtras("name")
        mTextView.setText(name);
}
}
```

**EDITED:** Error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object
>   reference

on this line:

```
Places places = randomPlaceList.get(position);
```

ERROR:

> Process: com.example.eugene.lafinalproduction, PID: 8352
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
>       at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
>       at com.example.eugene.lafinalproduction.ListViewPlaces$1.onComplete(ListViewPlaces.java:63)
>       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

The problem in this line:

```
randomPlaceList.add(placesList.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount)));
```

Comment: where is the error thrown? add also the error stacktrace

Comment: Added.@PierGiorgioMisley

Comment: Which line throws the NPE?

Comment: added@Code-Apprentice in hte bottom of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that your `randomPlaceList` is null.

*Since I can't see the app or the logics you performed to get the error, I just go based on what I see.*

The first stuff is that if you need to get the clicked item, it *should* be done by calling the `getItem(position)` method of your `adapter`; you can easily implement it like below:

```
@Override
public Places getItem(int position) {
    if(dataSet != null && position < dataSet.size()){
       return dataSet.get(position);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now from your `activity` you can simply perform a call like:

```
Places places = mAdapter.getItem(position);
```

Remember to add a reference to the `adapter` when you initialize it by adding `PlaceAdapter mAdapter;` in activity variables and replacing initialization with

```
mAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(randomPlaceList, getBaseContext());
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

---

reading the code quickly, I don't also find much sense to this:

```
this.randomPlaceList = randomPlaceList;
```

but maybe you cut out some code, but I prefer to report it to you, just in case :)

---

## Note to specify the error

The error is here and it is about variable refer:

```
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Places> placesList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Places place = document.toObject(Places.class);
                        placesList.add(place);
                    }                      
                    int placeCount = placesList.size();
                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();  

                    // In the line below, you specify a new ArrayList that is LOCAL, you don't refer to the Activity's object
                    ArrayList<Places> randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                        randomPlaceList.add(placesList.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount)));
                    }
                    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.place_list);
                    PlaceAdapter placeAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(randomPlaceList, getBaseContext());
                    mListView.setAdapter(placeAdapter);                    
            }
        });
```

You should replace it with:

```
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Places> placesList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Places place = document.toObject(Places.class);
                        placesList.add(place);
                    }                      
                    int placeCount = placesList.size();
                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

                    randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>(); //this is the activity's list
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                        randomPlaceList.add(placesList.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount)));
                    }
                    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.place_list);
                    PlaceAdapter placeAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(randomPlaceList, getBaseContext());
                    mListView.setAdapter(placeAdapter);                    
            }
        });
```

Otherwise the activity's list will always be null, since you never init it

Hope this helps

Comment: I used first part of your answer and it helps, the second part of answer made red all `OnItemClickListener` method, so I didn't replace line with `local refer`, that you say.@Pier Giorgio Misley

Comment: I edited an Main Activity class, that now worked.@Pier Giorgio Misley

Comment: Big thanks, you helped me so much!@Pier Giorgio Misley

Comment: @SpikeJohnson Glad it helped you! if you have more questions, I/we're here :)

Comment: @SpikeJohnson yeah I wrote it just to specify better the reasons for your error, but the first way is probably better ^^

Comment: Hi @Pier Giorgio Misley, it's again me, already was fine with, but I now run the app and find this error, nothing changes, already was fine, but now this error. I edited question.

Comment: @SpikeJohnson java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: means that count is less or equals 0

Comment: Can you please tell me in simple words? The problem in Adapter, or my Firestore?

Comment: @SpikeJohnson you added a row of code.. the error is in it.. the count is 0

Comment: I'm nothing to add@Pier Giorgio Misley. Just one time app run, another not. What I must to change, that it was run?

Comment: How count can be 0? Firestore is full, model class is good..@Pier Giorgio Misley

Comment: I added if(placeCount != 0){...} error is disapearnig, but ListView is emty@Pier Giorgio Misley

Comment: So it's problem in Firestore?@Pier Giorgio Misley

Comment: How in morning, there are was items, and now there not?@Pier Giorgio Misley

Comment: @SpikeJohnson only way for you to know is debugging.. debug the call and inspect variables, you will see if you get items or not

Answer (score 1):

Initialize you `randomPlaceList` in your `onCreate` method of `ListViewPlaces`.

```
randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Currently you are initializing your `randomPlaceList` in this way `this.randomPlaceList = randomPlaceList;` which is wrong because you are assigning same copy of `randomPlaceList`, its like **a = a**.

And delete your local variable `ArrayList<Places> randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();` which is inside `query.get().addOnCompleteListener();`

`getIntent().getExtras()` returns a `Bundle` that has values in **Key-Value** pairs(You can add multiple value of **Key-Value** pair to a Bundle) but you are not passing a `Bundle`, you are passing simply one **Key-Value** pair. So it is preferred to call `getStringExtra("name")` in your `Card_activity`.

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

Instead of

```
String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

Comment: It's error that is way all time, early in RecycleView all worked with `.getExtras.getString`. I place error in question.@Ghulam Moinul Quadir

Comment: @SpikeJohnson I have updated my answer. I think this may be helpful

Comment: The same error in the same place@Ghulam Moinul Quadir

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity, change this:

```
String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

To:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: It's error that is way all time, early in RecycleView all worked with .getExtras.getString. I place error in question.@Lucas Arrefelt

Comment: While the second is probably preferred, it is just shorthand for the first. These two lines of code do the exact same thing and will not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code. But let's just focus on your question. 
You should use

```
intent.getStringExtra
```

to get string data from previous activity, instead of using

```
intent.getExtras().getString("name");
```

getStringExtra and getExtras are different.

Comment: It's error that is way all time, early in RecycleView all worked with `.getExtras.getString`. I place error in question.@Chauyan

Comment: Both of these do the same thing.

Comment: I think for that exception, you should the is randomPlaceList is null or not and if this variable is not null, you should check its size again to avoid the index out of boundary exception @SpikeJohnson